# Retrieving Files from Broken Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, files, sudo

I run Ubuntu 14.04. I recently ran the command `sudo apt-get -f install`, which, for some reason, ended up removing the boot files.

So, I reinstalled Ubuntu on a different partition. However, I would like to get some of my personal files from the first installation back. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` wont remove files. if your files are missing, that cannot be held responsible for it. For recovering data, simply search for data recovery in linux or ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you open Nautilus, you are able to see the partition with your broken installation, you can explore that and copy the files you need on your new installation.